# Register to an event after login / create account in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I need to send a link by email like that:

```
http://laravel.dev:8000/events/{eventId}/register/
```

I put this route inside my auth middleware, so that if user is not logged or has no account, user get to the authentication page.

Thing is after login, system forgets what was the initial wanted action ( Register to an event ) and redirect user to dashboard.

Off course, problem is more dificult when registering, because user needs to register, receive a mail, and then, when he activates his account, initial action should be performed...

What is the best way to perform this kind of thing???

Comment: Can you show us the existing code for the middleware? Then we can draw some conclusions about how you're handling all of this and advise accordingly.

Comment: I have coded no middleware. I just have the built in Authenticate

Answer (score 0):

You can use Laravel's session id (which is set automatically) with `Session::getId()` and store it with the initial wanted action to a database.

Answer (score 0):

Are you perhaps looking for `redirect()->intendend(route('route'))`? (Docs/API: https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Routing/Redirector.html#method_intended).

That will redirect the user to the url they were trying to visit before being "blocked off" with the sign in page.

Dunno if the value is kept when registering though; there you might want to capture the requested URL with a middleware, and save it to the session.

Then when successfully signing up, redirect the user to the intended route via the standard `redirect()->route('route')`.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be pretty close to what I want. I checked the Trait AuthenticatesUser that I use, and it already use this function :  return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath()); So in a way, it should be posible if I can pass a custom redirectPath variable, but I don't know how to do it. Any Idea?

Comment: If you check the source here: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Routing/Redirector.php#L97-L101 – you can see that it just takes the `url.intended`-session key. So you should be able to set your own URL with `$request->session()->put('url.intended', 'your-url-here')`.

Comment: Oh, by the way. Perhaps I undertood you wrong here; if it is just the `redirectPath` you want to change, you can just put `protected $redirectTo = '/url';` in your controller. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28981313/property-redirectpath-and-redirectto-set-location-laravel-trait-authenticatesan for example.

Comment: Yes, I saw both way to do, but I still doesn't understando how to use it as I have no way nor place to fire it. I use a URL that send me to Login first, because user is not authenticated. It will not go to the controller where I should write those. So, Where in my code should I change the url.intend variable, this is the point I was not able to solve